# Get list of data after recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

I need to run through db using recursion and get a list of results at the end. Function works correct (if print unrem) but I cann't return the list of results.

```
def find_locks(item, ids):
    if item.video_id:
        #print (item.video_id, ids)
        return (item.video_id, ids)
    for i in CatalogItem.objects.filter(parent=item):
        if i.is_lock:
            find_locks(i, ids.append(i.id))
        else:
            find_locks(i, ids)
```

How can I get the list results?

Comment: Can you write some input and output examples?

Comment: you only return results in the 'if' branch.

Comment: you need an assignment for find_locks or return find_locks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a recursive generator instead of building a list:

```
def find_locks(item, ids):
    if item.video_id:
        yield (item.video_id, ids)
    for i in CatalogItem.objects.filter(parent=item):
        nxt = ids + [i.id] if i.is_lock else ids
        for x in find_locks(i, nxt):
            yield x
```

In python 3.3 you can use `yield from` for the last part.

Comment: I think this variant is the best, but **ids** always return as empty list, the real data has lists with ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store each result in a list and return that at the end:

```
def find_locks(item, ids):
    if item.video_id:
        return [(item.video_id, ids)]
    result = []
    for i in CatalogItem.objects.filter(parent=item):
        if i.is_lock:
            result.extend(find_locks(i, ids + [i.id]))
        else:
            result.extend(find_locks(i, ids))
    return result
```

Note that you need to return each item in a list as well because other calls to `find_locks` expect to receive a list as return value.

Comment: I know it was in the OP by greg as well, but `ids.append(i.id)` will return `None`, which is probably not what he had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
def find_locks(item, ids):
    if item.video_id:        
        return [(item.video_id, ids)]
    res = []
    for i in CatalogItem.objects.filter(parent=item):
        if i.is_lock:
            res.extend(find_locks(i, ids + [i.id]))
        else:
            res.extend(find_locks(i, ids))
    return res
```

In the base case you return list with the only one item included. If it's not the base case, you make a new list, execute recursive call, extend the list with result of recursive call and return this list.

Comment: I know it was in the OP by greg as well, but `ids.append(i.id)` will return `None`, which is probably not what he had in mind.